# How to fix GET http://localhost/storage/users/default.jpg 404 (Not Found) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm facing a problem that return me :
`GET http://localhost/storage/users/default.jpg 404 (Not Found)`.

I have storage link (a shortcut) created and a users/default.jpg file in it.
I've called it in blade like this :
`{{Storage::disk('public')->url('users/'. Auth::user()->image)}}`.

But it's not working. Any one can help me? How can i fix this issue. I can't find the problem.

My code :

```
<div class="user-pic">
   <img src="{{Storage::disk('public')->url('users/'. Auth::user()->image)}}" alt="users" class="rounded-circle" width="50" />
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="user-pic"><img src="{{Storage::disk('public')->url('users/'. Auth::user()->image)}}" alt="users" class="rounded-circle" width="50" /></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the command `php artisan storage:link`, you'll end up accessing your assets files in the storage directory using this syntax : `asset('storage/file.txt');`

If you wish access it inside a blade template, you'll write something like this :

```
<img src= "{{ asset('storage/users/' . Auth::user()->image) }}">
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is the exact way you wanted to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Storage folder can not be called publicly, you should create a symlink using

```
php artisan storage:link
```

and then you can use

```
$path = asset('storage/' . $filepath/$fileName);
```

to retrieve the file,

refer [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: I have created symlink using php artisan storage:link command but its not working

Comment: @ShahadatHossain Are you able to see your storage folder inside public folder?

Comment: Yeah I have a shortcut folder inside public foldel. When I hited this php artisan storage:link command it was created.

Comment: @ShahadatHossain Can you tell me public folder path to your file?

Comment: My project file name is redline. Inside this folder app, config, dattabase and public etc..

Comment: @ShahadatHossain I am asking about the file path you want to retrieve, if you will open public folder, there will be storage folder inside storage folder what is the next folders that leads to your file?

Comment: @ShahadatHossain if my answer is helpful, you may like to upvote and if it solved your problem, you may like to upvote it as well as mark it as correct, so that it will be easier for future visitors to get correct answer.

Comment: Inside storage then my users folder then image file.

Comment: @ShahadatHossain Do you want my help to display it or you are able to display it now?

Comment: @ShahadatHossain Do you still need my help to display the image ?

Answer (score 1):

You can direct access your public folder by writing this `<img src="{{ asset('imgs/logo/global.png') }}"/>` it will take path of local like `/public/imgs/logo/global.png`

Answer (score 0):

in your file `.env` try `APP_URL=http://localhost:8000`

after that it will be like: http://localhost/8000/storage/users/default.jpg